# Django: annotating counts/sums of objects with ForeignKey - wrong output

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I have models with foreign keys set:

```
STATUS = Choices('active', 'inactive', 'deleted')

class Project(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(
        choices=STATUS,
        default=STATUS.active,
        max_length=20
    )
    objects = ProjectManager()

    def delete(self):
        self.status = STATUS.deleted
        self.save()

class Observation(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(
        choices=STATUS,
        default=STATUS.active,
        max_length=20
    )
    location = models.ForeignKey(
        Location, related_name='locations'
    )
    project = models.ForeignKey(
        Project, related_name='observations'
    )
    history = HistoricalRecords()
    objects = ObservationManager()

    def delete(self):
        self.status = STATUS.deleted
        self.save()

class Comment(models.Model):
    status = models.CharField(
        choices=STATUS,
        default=STATUS.active,
        max_length=20
    )
    commentto = models.ForeignKey(
        Observation, related_name='comments'
    )
    objects = CommentManager()

    def delete(self):
        self.status = STATUS.deleted
        self.save()
```

As you can see, there's possibility to change the status of an object. Also, there's a status called "deleted". So instead of deleting an actual object, I just set the status to "deleted", and then manager takes care of the rest (returns everything what's needed apart from deleted items).

On the view, I want to return all projects, but with a number of observations and comments in total (per project). Also, because there are hundreds of projects, I want to reduce the queries as much as possible.

So I end up with this solution:

```
Project.objects.all().annotate(
    observations_count=Sum(
        Case(
            When(
                ~Q(observations__status='deleted') &
                Q(observations__isnull=False),
                then=1
            ),
            default=0,
            output_field=IntegerField()
        ),
        distinct=True
    ),
    comments_count=Sum(
        Case(
            When(
                ~Q(observations__status='deleted') &
                ~Q(observations__comments___status='deleted') &
                Q(observations__comments__isnull=False),
                then=1
            ),
            default=0,
            output_field=IntegerField()
        ),
        distinct=True
    )
)
```

Basically, I want to count all observations, that have different than "deleted" and that actually exist, then I do the same with comments.

However, this gives me wrong results...

For example, if I create one observation and two comments, then I delete one comment, it will count as: 2 observations, 1 comment (which is totally wrong).

Or if I add two observations, one with two comments, but delete one comment, and another with one comment but delete that observation, it will give me: 2 observations, 1 comment.

Now if I go with this:

```
projects = Project.objects.all()

for project in projects:
    observations = project.observations.all()
    project.observations_count = len(observations)
    project.comments_count = Comment.objects.filter(commentto=observations).count()
```

It gives me the correct results. BUT, obviously, this makes waaaaayy to many SQL queries, and is no good for me.

Can someone please give me any suggestions on how to try and solve this problem?

**The solution I went for...**

So I couldn't get this working in any way... And end up solving it like this:

I added new field num_comments = models.IntegerField(default=0) to Observation model, which is updated each time a comment is added/removed. Then I managed to count everything correctly like this:

```
Project.objects.all().annotate(
    observations_count=Sum(
        Case(
            When(
                ~Q(observations__status='deleted') &
                Q(observations__isnull=False),
                then=1
            ),
            default=0,
            output_field=IntegerField()
        ),
        distinct=True
    ),
    comments_count=Sum(
        Case(
            When(
                ~Q(observations__status='deleted') &
                Q(observations__isnull=False),
                then='observations__num_comments'
            ),
            default=0,
            output_field=IntegerField()
        ),
        distinct=True
    )
)
```

This is not where I was going in the first place, but does the job... Anyway, if someone has a better solution, please don't hesitate to drop a message below.

Comment: Please check the answer and let know whether it works. Just curious :)

Answer (score 0):

This is quite tricky. Can you please try below,

```
projects = Project.objects.\
    exclude(observations__status='deleted', observations__comments___status='deleted').\
    filter(observations__status__isnull=False, observations__comments___status__isnull=False).\
    annotate(count_observations=Count('observations__id'), count_comments=Count('observations__comments__id'))
```

and you should get the counts as,

```
for p in projects:
    print p.count_observations
    print p.count_comments
```

**Update:**

Actually the above query won't work as per the requirement. So I guess this has to be done in 2 steps. Please try below,

```
projects = Project.objects.\
    exclude(observations__status='deleted').\
    filter(observations__status__isnull=False).\
    annotate(count_observations=Count('observations__id'))

projects = projects.\
    exclude(observations__comments___status='deleted').\
    filter(observations__comments___status__isnull=False).\
    annotate(count_comments=Count('observations__comments__id'))

for p in projects:
    print p.count_observations
    print p.count_comments
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, your solution is no good for me. What I didn't tell in the original post, that besides comments, I have a few more things to count. This would create too many separate requests. However, I managed to accomplish the task (I will post the solution in original response due to lack of characters here).